# Python can not get links from web page

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am writing python script which gets links from website. But when I tried with this [web page](http://www.meinpaket.de/de/shopsList.html?page=1) I was unable to get links. My script is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

datas = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'tsrImg'})
for data in datas:
    link = data.find('a')
    print str(link.href)
```

it prints only None, can anyone explain why it is so???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
str(link.href)
```

With:

```
link.get('href')
```

It will look like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.meinpaket.de/de/shopsList.html?page=1'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
datas = soup.findAll('div', {'class':'tsrImg'})
for data in datas:
    link = data.find('a')
    print link.get('href')
```

Outputs:

```
/de/~-office-partner-gmbh-;jsessionid=11957F27FC2D888A34532D9848C922FB.as03
/de/~-24selling-de;jsessionid=11957F27FC2D888A34532D9848C922FB.as03
/de/~abalisi-kuenstlerbedarf-shop;jsessionid=11957F27FC2D888A34532D9848C922FB.as03
/de/~abcmeineverpackung-de-kg;jsessionid=11957F27FC2D888A34532D9848C922FB.as03
/de/~ability;jsessionid=11957F27FC2D888A34532D9848C922FB.as03
/de/~ac-foto-handels-gmbh;jsessionid=11957F27FC2D888A34532D9848C922FB.as03
/de/~ac-sat-corner-inh-dirk-hahn;jsessionid=11957F27FC2D888A34532D9848C922FB.as03
/de/~adamo-fashion-gmbh-shop;jsessionid=11957F27FC2D888A34532D9848C922FB.as03
/de/~adapter-markt;jsessionid=11957F27FC2D888A34532D9848C922FB.as03
/de/~adko;jsessionid=11957F27FC2D888A34532D9848C922FB.as03
```